# Are There Any Rules For Wearing Neck Pendant Of Your Ishth-Dev

Tags: bhakti

Do Hindu texts specify any rules for wearing a pendant of your Ishth-Dev around your neck ?

That it should or shouldn’t be on when sleep or shower or take a bath, or things like that ?

I want to wear a simple metal idol or small picture locket of Devi.

Have hesitated to do this because there are so many rules I never knew before and I’ve accidentally done some stuffs incorrectly. Many mistakes as a beginner on bhakti path. Trying to be more careful now and check things first

Comment: Maybe I’ll start wearing it then, cause assuming there would be comments/replies saying not to wear it, if was an issue 